# Why am I unable to sign out using devise_token_auth and curl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rspec, devise, devise-token-auth

I'm using rails-api with devise_token_auth for authentication. I am able to sign in without issue via:

```
curl -i http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in -F email="user@nowhere.org" -F password="password"
```

However, sign out fails with a 404 and the error "User was not found or was not logged in." via:

```
curl -X DELETE -i http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_out
```

I have tried variations of this command with multiple combinations of parameters and header values, such as:

```
curl -X DELETE -i http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_out -F email="user@nowhere.org" -H Access-Token="Ae1yaTYLkSAgdhz3LtPAZg" -H Client="9AmYF6NS8tP6EOD5nPSuxw" -H Expiry="1443073493" -H Uid="user@nowhere.org" -H Token-Type="Bearer"
```

To no avail. A similarly constructed RSpec test also fails with the same response and error, and the logs indicate the request was processed via DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#destroy as JSON.

Of course, I'm not actually using curl for authentication; just verification of the request structure before writing the relevant code.

Comment: I think the header needs to be -H Authorization="uid=blahblah" or something similar. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750 and https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

Answer (score 10):

Answering my own question, I wasn't returning certain sign_in response header values correctly with the sign_out request.

[I found a related post](http://matthughes.io/securing-a-rails-api-with-devise/) which pointed out some of the critical headers. The trick is to capture the access-token, client, and uid header values from the sign_in response, then include them as parameters in the sign_out request:

```
curl -i -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_out -F access-token="Ae1yaTYLkSAgdhz3LtPAZg" -F client="9AmYF6NS8tP6EOD5nPSuxw" -F uid="user@nowhere.org"
```

Here's an RSpec test to illustrate and verify:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Authentication", type: :request do

  it "logs a user out" do
    user = User.create!(
      name: "Some Dude", 
      email: "user@nowhere.org",
      password: "password", 
      confirmed_at: Date.today
    )

    # initial sign in to generate a token and response
    post api_v1_user_session_path, {
      email: user.email, 
      password: user.password
    }

    expect(user.reload.tokens.count).to eq 1

    # sign out request using header values from sign in response
    delete destroy_api_v1_user_session_path, {
      "access-token": response.header["access-token"], 
      client: response.header["client"], 
      uid: response.header["uid"]
    }

    response_body = JSON.load(response.body)
    expect(response_body["errors"]).to be_blank
    expect(response.status).to eq 200
    # user token should be deleted following sign out
    expect(user.reload.tokens.count).to eq 0
  end

end
```

Comment: I'm using the same thing , checked the headers but still not make it work

Comment: post link is also expired

Comment: I prefer to do it this way `curl -H "access-token: HbJiAUvTFoPWbCnHvdplDQ" -H "client: 0TtJ9D7TyeSTkfz1KatYug" -H "uid: busation4@gmail.com" -X DELETE "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_out"`

Answer (score 2):

In details, do the following steps:

Step 1:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in -d "{\"email\":\"user@example.com\",\"password\":\"password\"}"
```

You'll get a response like this:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /api/v1/auth/sign_in HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 50
>
* upload completely sent off: 50 out of 50 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Access-Token: BqXcWQi0-9faLyxP1LnUKw
< Token-Type: Bearer
< Client: dYSqVgM9VT6fV9Y5MFWpJQ
< Expiry: 1465679853
< Uid: user@example.com
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Etag: W/"9ad6a23f014a744a7ec83b4e0e9d27aa"
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< X-Request-Id: 6566bd38-1ad7-491a-a1ab-e41458b9b704
< X-Runtime: 0.184807
< Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.3.0/2015-12-25)
< Date: Sat, 28 May 2016 21:17:33 GMT
< Content-Length: 135
< Connection: Keep-Alive
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"data":{"id":6,"provider":"email","uid":"user@example.com","name":"testuser","nickname":null,"image":null,"email":"user@example.com"}}%
```

Step 2:

Now, you want to sign the user out.

```
curl -i -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_out -F access-token="BqXcWQi0-9faLyxP1LnUKw" -F client="dYSqVgM9VT6fV9Y5MFWpJQ" -F uid="user@example.com"
```

You'll get a response like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Etag: W/"7363e85fe9edee6f053a4b319588c086"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: 8f7a297a-6a72-4c9d-a210-48c29fb4bfe0
X-Runtime: 0.095060
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.3.0/2015-12-25)
Date: Sat, 28 May 2016 21:19:18 GMT
Content-Length: 16
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"success":true}%
```

In step 2, I've added the **access-token** and **client** as per the response that we received in step 1 (**Access-Token: BqXcWQi0-9faLyxP1LnUKw** and **Client: dYSqVgM9VT6fV9Y5MFWpJQ**).

That's it! :)

I took the help of @user3006381's answer! All credits to him.