# DeviseToken Auth Not Receiving token/header data to logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, authentication, devise-token-auth

I am having an issue getting devise_token_auth logout working.

I am working based on these SO:

[How to set header and options in axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578844/how-to-set-header-and-options-in-axios)

[Why am I unable to sign out using devise_token_auth and curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507637/why-am-i-unable-to-sign-out-using-devise-token-auth-and-curl)

This is the devise token auth, destroy method. It does reach this method and stops at a breakpoint.

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/c92258038c05fcc8f6a0374ccce2e63b9f8d5312/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb#L48

```
    def destroy
      # remove auth instance variables so that after_action does not run
      user = remove_instance_variable(:@resource) if @resource
      client = @token.client
      @token.clear!

      if user && client && user.tokens[client]
        user.tokens.delete(client)
        user.save!

        yield user if block_given?

        render_destroy_success
      else
        render_destroy_error
      end
    end
```

`@token` is set in another method and it doesn't appear to be called. I don't quite get how this method is supposed to clear tokens.

My `@token` is `#<struct DeviseTokenAuth::TokenFactory::Token client=nil, token=nil, token_hash=nil, expiry=nil>` and `@resource`  is nil at my break point/top of the method.

Client Request (Vue):

```
 methods: {
      headers() {
        const config = {
          headers: {
            "uid": localStorage.getItem("uid"),
            "client": localStorage.getItem("client"),
            "access-token": localStorage.getItem("access-token")
          }
        }
        return config
      },

      async handleLogOut() {
        // e.preventDefault();
        const headers = this.headers()

        localStorage.removeItem('access-token')
        localStorage.removeItem('uid')
        localStorage.removeItem('client')

        this.logOut();

        let response = await axios.get('api/v1/auth/sign_out', null, headers)
      }
    }
```

Routes:

```
 destroy_api_user_session GET    /api/v1/auth/sign_out(.:format)                                                          api/v1/sessions#destroy
```

What am I doing wrong?
How is the destroy method working?

Comment: I think why your destroy method isn't working is because you're using `axios.get()`, and I believe you should use `axios.delete()` instead, because for devise sign out is using `delete` request method.

Comment: I get this `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/api/v1/auth/sign_out"):` I will add the routes I have. The routes could be different for devise vs devise_token_auth.

Comment: could you show me the `routes.rb`? because I never use `devise_token_auth` but I think `destroy` must be a `delete` request method. as in [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/1220) you can check that he is using `delete` method

Comment: ah right by default. I changed it in the config though to use a get route. [config.sign_out_via = :get](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/c92258038c05fcc8f6a0374ccce2e63b9f8d5312/test/dummy/config/initializers/devise.rb#L254)

Comment: I see you already get the answer, glad to see that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I missed this `before_action` method:

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/c92258038c05fcc8f6a0374ccce2e63b9f8d5312/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/concerns/set_user_by_token.rb#L26

This is where it takes your headers, checks them and sets instance variables.

By finding this I realized I was not sending the headers that I thought I was sending. I changed my http request it works fine.

`axios.get('api/v1/auth/sign_out', headers)`

Side Note:
The logout action by default in devise is `delete` but this can be modified:

```
  config.sign_out_via = :get
```